# Hiding multiple elements by value with CSS

Tags: css

I have some input elements that I am looking to hide about 50 of. This is the code I am using to hide 1 of them, but how can i implement it to hide say value 11-60?

```
input[value="11"] {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edited**

For what you want, it's better to use any preprocessor like **Sass** or **Less** to end your misery. For Example.

```
$selector: 'input';
@for $i from 1 to 10 {
    $selector: $selector + '[value=' + $i + ']';
}

#{$selector} {
    // style
}
```

In pure **css**, you will have to define each one of them. Something like this.

```
.input[value=10],
.input[value=11],
.input[value=12]
...
.input[value=60] {
    // style
}
```

But digging a bit more there is a `:in-range` pseudoclass.

Which you can use for `<input type=number>`

For example:

**.css**

```
input:in-range {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

**.html**

```
<input type="number" min="5" max="10" value="7">
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this is not an option on the page atm :(

Comment: why, tell me?!.

Comment: I've edited my anwser. Actually the last aproach will help you most.